# can't catch PDOException when my query has error, why?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, exception, pdo

I'm using CodeIgniter and I have the following code to fetch all records from database:

```
try {
     $sth = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($query);  
     $sth->bindParam(':something', $something, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $sth->execute();  
     //...
    }
     catch (PDOException $e) {
            //error goes here
    }
```

I made a mistake on $query which I put LIMIT right before ORDER BY. ie:

```
SELECT `something` from some_table LIMIT 0, 10 ORDER BY some_other_field DESC (bad)
```

instead of

```
SELECT `something` from some_table ORDER BY some_other_field DESC LIMIT 0, 10 (correct)
```

but when I run my code, I didn't catch any `PDOException` (just return no result), even I set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

so why is that? so how to catch the query error?

***Update 1***: In CodeIgniter pdo_driver.php file, I have already changed the db_connect() and db_pconnect():

```
function db_connect()
    {
        $this->options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $this->options['PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES'] = FALSE;

        return new PDO($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->options);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Persistent database connection
     *
     * @access  private called by the base class
     * @return  resource
     */
    function db_pconnect()
    {
        $this->options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $this->options['PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT'] = TRUE;

        return new PDO($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->options);
    }
```

However I won't catch any PDOException, unless I added:
$this->db->conn_id->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
before I run the execute(). Why?

Comment: After calling `execute()` you can call `$sth->errorCode();` which would return five zeros `00000` or something like `HY0001` if it errored. Also I think you need to call `$sth->bindParam(':something', $something, PDO::PARAM_INT);` before `$sth->execute();` **[PHP bindparam docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)**

Comment: Post the text of the error message.

Comment: It should throw an exception, and will here. Are you sure you are using the _same_ connection you set the the error mode attribute on? No reconnect / other object or anything? What happens if you set it _again_ explicitly right before your `prepare`?

Comment: @Wrikken yes, if I add $this->db->conn_id->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); right before execute then the error is shown, but if I directly modify pdo_driver and change the db_connect() from $this->options['PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE'] = PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT;
 to $this->options['PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE'] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION; then it doesn't show

Comment: @PHP bindparam docs yes, bindParam line is right before the execute line, it's just when I copied my code here I made a mistake. I have edited my post.

Comment: That's not the way to set options, the `PDO` object doesn't have a magic `->options` array which would cause different behavior when setting things there. Just use `$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` at that point instead and everything will probably work as intended.

Comment: @Wrikken actually that's the code in codeigniter: $this->options['PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE'] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $this->options['PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES'] = FALSE;
        return new PDO($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->options);

Comment: Aha, I see: change `$this->options['PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE']` to `$this->options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE]` (lose the quotes).

Comment: even i take out the single quotes, it won't catch the PDOException. I have to put the setAttribute right before the execute line in order to make it work.